# Invoke Attributes from Thread c#

Tags: c#, winforms, invoke

First, i'm using the "quickest" invoke call i found here on StackOverflow and would like to stick to it, IF possible.

When i need to add an item from a thread to a listview on my WindowsForm, i call it like that:

```
lv_ProcessMonitor.Invoke(new Action(() => lv_ProcessMonitor.Items.Add(item)));
```

But when i need to access it's items in the same thread, or reading the item's tag, i don't know how to invoke correctly, or if i even have to:

```
foreach(ListViewItem item in lv_ProcessMonitor.Items)
{
    if (item.SubItems[1].Text == "Running")
    {
        Process p = item.Tag as Process;            <--- THIS THROWS ERROR
        if (!p.HasExited)
        {
            process_buttons[p.ProcessName].Enabled = false;
        }
    }
    else if (item.SubItems[1].Text == "Not Running")
    {
         process_buttons[item.SubItems[0].Text].Enabled = true;
    }
}
```

As shown in code above, the line i marked throws an error at runtime with code "Access denied" (Win32Exception). I guess it's because i don't invoke a single item i get through foreach.

So the question is: How do you invoke attributes like that (Tag, Subitems etc) with the simplest method mentioned above?

Comment: That exception is strange. Are you sure it's that line? The [reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/System.Windows.Forms/R/93558ccae31ebe5d.html) doesn't tell how an exception could be thrown here. But maybe the line above.

Comment: Don't. If you check *any* related SO question, the answer is that you *can't* modify a UI element from a background thread. *Don't* use the UI to store data anyway. Most definitely don't store a *Process* as a Tag. Use a list, array or dictionary to store the Process objects.

Comment: As for updating the UI when something changes, either use data binding or call a method that will read the data and update the controls.

Comment: I'm not so sure for the cause of problem. It can be the access from a different thread. You can check with `item.InvokeRequired` property if a invoke is needed. For some properties/function Invoke must be used _(even for reading of values)_.